# How to use Python mechanize to save a page inlcuding images on the page

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

So I understand that mechanize can make python script behave exactly like a browser.
With a browser, I can save a loaded page into local disk, including the images in the page
How can I do this with mechanize ?
It doesn't seem to be able to save images on the page

I'm using example from [This page](http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this however here are the steps you'll need to take

- open the page with mechanize or urllib2
- get the html
- parse html with lxml
- find all image urls
- for each image url open with mechanize or urllib2 and save

In this situation mechanize doesn't really offer you anything over urllib2 if you only want to deal with one page and you don't need to login to get to it. You might find [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) useful for this task.